# Run two functions in the exact same time

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to `slideUp()` a div, and when its sliding up, I want to move it down by `animate()` - in the exact same time .

what I have done so far :

```
    ln = jQuery("Selector");
    ln.slideUp(1500, function() {
        ln.animate({top: '150px'}, 'slow');
        var Html = jQuery('#last' + id1).html() + jQuery('#last' + id2).html();
        ln.html(Html);
    });
```

**But** it slides up first, and **then** moves down 150px.

I want to  call these two functions (`slideUp` and `animate` )  in the exact same time, I want to know is it possible or not?

Or does my problem have an easier way to solve ?

**P.S** : I think this kind of questions has been asked before, like [**this**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15422927/run-two-jquery-functions-at-the-same-time), but Its not my answer if you read it completely.

Comment: Well, technically it's not possible to run two functions at the same time because JavaScript is single threaded. In your code, you are *explicitly* calling `.animate` *after* `.slideUp` is done. That's what the callback is for. However, you can still run both animations at the same time, e.g. if you just change `.animate` to perform the same animation as `.slideUp`.

Comment: @FelixKling - he means that he wants the two animations to appear to run at the same time.  This is possible.

Comment: @jfriend00: That's why I said *technically* ;) (and I was more referring to the title actually)

Comment: @AlienArrays -  what ? how ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do this by using `.animate()` for both operations and just specifying both changes with properties that you pass to animate.  The slideup can be done by specifying a final height of `0` for animate.  Using this single animation, jQuery will run both changes together as part of the same animation sequence.

```
ln.animate({top: '150px', height: 0}, 'slow');
```

Working demo: http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/kKsa4/